# Object Oriented Programming "Produce A"

Tags: oop

How to represent a "Produce A" relationship in OOP? I know such one doesn't exist but I want to represent the relationship of an object producing another object. For example, a chicken produces an egg, a musical instrument produces sound. How to represent this relationship?

Comment: This may be better on [programmers.se]

Comment: A dependency with stereotype `<<create>>`

Answer (score 2):

The UML mechanism for showing that is a dependency relationship with stereotype `<<create>>`. In general,

```
           <<create>>
Client -----------------> Supplier
```

More information about dependencies can be found in this [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_%28UML%29).